# Why use FormLayout instead of a VerticalLayout in Vaadin?

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin7

With `Formlayout` all your captions are to the left of the field. This is fine if you only have forms with one column of fields, but as soon as you have more complex forms such as a Firstname and Lastname on the same row that you want to put side by side, you can't use `FormLayout`, at least not if you want captions for the fields to be consistent, either left or above the fields. Yes you can wrap them in an `HorizontalLayout` and set an `InputPrompt` in a `FormLayout`, but that doesn't always work for more complex forms because sometimes you still need the caption. With a `VerticalLayout` at least all your captions will be consistent.

All that to say what's the advantage of using a `FormLayout` over a `VerticalLayout`? I want all the captions to be consistent, either top or left, and if I use anything but a single column of fields than I'm out of luck. I believe validation can also be done outside of a `FormLayout` so I'm not sure this is a pro limited to the `FormLayout`.

If I just used a `VerticalLayout` then I get all the captions above the field, and this will be consistent for all fields, even if I have to do any advanced layouts and combine many different types of Layouts, such as Firstname and Lastname on the same row, or an address row where I want the city and Zip code fields to be different sizes, etc.

There must be an advantage to the `FormLayout` over the `VerticalLayout` but I can't see it...

Comment: and what if there isn't?  what if it's just a convenience for other usescases?

Comment: That could very well be, and if that's the case then that's the answer :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There really isn't much into it. `FormLayout` was used by deprecated now `com.vaadin.ui.Form`. We can speculate that the class was probably created to provide default settings for the `com.vaadin.ui.Form`.

Differences are stated in JavaDoc too:

- captions are on the left
- validation is shown in between the caption
  and the component
- difference in default spacing and margins settings

You can also take a look at the server side code of both classes. It looks very similar and therefore the logic side of both layouts is exactly the same.

Source: [the JavaDoc](https://vaadin.com/api/7.6.4/com/vaadin/ui/FormLayout.html) and my own experience.

Comment: So really the biggest difference, at least if you try to combine it with different layouts in a form for more complex use cases, is that the caption is to the left which means that the caption is not consistently located. Otherwise the other differences are fairly minor (well exception that the validation is nice).

Comment: Thank you for the confirmation, it's appreciated.